# Can't get a simple Master/Detail-pattern Xamarin.Forms App to work when emulating in VS17

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have been having some problems building my very first simple cross-platformed application for Android and iOS.

So I've created a Visual Studio 2017 project chosen these settings:

- Type: Cross Platform App (Xamarin) in Visual C#
- Template: Blank App
- UI Technology: Xamarin.Forms
- Code Sharing Strategy: Portable Class Library (PCL)

And followed some different tutorials on this, but the code and pattern is all the same it seems. But after a lot of trouble, I am stuck with this result:

When trying to emulate on 'Android_Accelerated_Nougat (Android 7.1 - API 25)', the app opens, and the menu works, but I can't get the 'Master'-page to show anything, even if I change to "Mainpage = new App1.Page1()" in 'App.xaml.cs'

When trying to emulate on 'KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone (Android 4.4 - API 19)' it won't open at all. Just crashes instantly.
Actually tried on some more too, they also crashed instantly.

[image: Picture of Solution Explorer]

The critical code files:

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MSCommunity_Xamarin"
         x:Class="App1.MainPage">

<MasterDetailPage.Master>
<ContentPage Title="Menu"
             BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8">

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#e74c3c"
                 HeightRequest="75">

      <Label Text="Menu dawgii"
             FontSize="20"
             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
             TextColor="White"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList"
              RowHeight="60"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"
              ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>

            <!-- Main design for our menu items -->
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Padding="20,10,0,10"
                         Spacing="20">

              <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                     WidthRequest="40"
                     HeightRequest="40"
                     VerticalOptions="Center" />

              <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                     FontSize="Medium"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
<NavigationPage>

</NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using App1.MenuItems;
using App1.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{

public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{

    public List<MasterPageItem> MenuList { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        MenuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();

        var page1 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 1", Icon = "itemIcon1.png", TargetType = typeof(Page1) };
        var page2 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 2", Icon = "itemIcon2.png", TargetType = typeof(Page2) };
        var page3 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 3", Icon = "itemIcon3.png", TargetType = typeof(Page3) };

        // Adding menu items to menuList
        MenuList.Add(page1);
        MenuList.Add(page2);
        MenuList.Add(page3);

        // Setting our list to be ItemSource for ListView in MainPage.xaml
        navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = MenuList;

        // Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page
        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Page1)));
    }

    // Event for Menu Item selection, here we are going to handle navigation based
    // on user selection in menu ListView
    private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
        Type page = item.TargetType;

        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
        IsPresented = false;
    }
}
}
```

MasterPageItem.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App1.MenuItems
{

public class MasterPageItem
{

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
}
}
```

Page1.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App1.Views.Page1">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Welcome to FastDelivery Page 22222" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And is the same on all Page*.xaml files...

App.xaml.cs (Tried so many different options in this file without result...)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var navPage = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Page1)));
        var mdp = new MasterDetailPage()
        {
            Master = new MenuPage(),
            Detail = navPage
        };

        MainPage = mdp;
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
}
```

Git: https://github.com/napzter13/masterdetail

// Output

Build log:

```
            1>------ Build started: Project: App1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
            1>  App1 -> C:\ShortApps\App1\App1\App1\bin\Debug\App1.dll
            2>------ Build started: Project: App1.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
            2>  App1.Android -> C:\ShortApps\App1\App1\App1.Android\bin\Debug\App1.Android.dll
            3>Starting deploy 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
            3>Starting emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
            3>Validating emulator arguments...
            3>Determining if emulator is already running...
            3>Preparing virtual machine...
            3>Launching emulator...
            3>Emulator launched successfully.
            3>Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone is running.
            3>Waiting for emulator to be ready...
            3>Deploying 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
            3>Build started.
            3>Project "App1.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):
            3>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\Users\Chronic\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" 
            3>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\Chronic\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\com.companyname.App1-Signed-Unaligned.apk C:\ShortApps\App1\App1\App1.Android\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.companyname.App1.apk androiddebugkey 
            3>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2047-10-28) or after any future revocation date.
            3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\ShortApps\App1\App1\App1.Android\bin\Debug\com.companyname.App1-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.companyname.App1-Signed.apk" 
            3>Done building project "App1.Android.csproj".
            3>Build succeeded.
            3>Deploy successfully on 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone
            ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
            ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Debug log:

```
            Android application is debugging.
            11-04 23:11:00.690 D/dalvikvm( 1254): Late-enabling CheckJNI
            11-04 23:11:00.706 D/dalvikvm( 1254): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.companyname.App1-2/libmonodroid.so 0xa9052830
            11-04 23:11:00.706 D/dalvikvm( 1254): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.companyname.App1-2/libmonodroid.so 0xa9052830
            11-04 23:11:00.722 W/monodroid( 1254): Creating public update directory: `/data/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__`
            11-04 23:11:00.722 W/monodroid( 1254): Using override path: /data/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__
            11-04 23:11:00.722 W/monodroid( 1254): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__
            11-04 23:11:00.722 W/monodroid( 1254): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/../legacy/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__
            11-04 23:11:00.726 W/monodroid( 1254): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
            11-04 23:11:00.726 W/monodroid( 1254): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
            11-04 23:11:00.730 W/monodroid( 1254): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/../legacy/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
            11-04 23:11:00.730 W/monodroid( 1254): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/com.companyname.App1-2/libmonosgen-2.0.so
            11-04 23:11:00.734 W/monodroid( 1254): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
            11-04 23:11:00.734 W/monodroid-debug( 1254): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:29224,server=y,embedding=1
            11-04 23:11:00.894 W/monodroid-debug( 1254): Accepted stdout connection: 43
            11-04 23:11:01.694 D/Mono    ( 1254): Image addref mscorlib[0xb80f96d0] -> mscorlib.dll[0xb80f2620]: 2
            11-04 23:11:01.694 D/Mono    ( 1254): Prepared to set up assembly 'mscorlib' (mscorlib.dll)
            11-04 23:11:01.698 D/Mono    ( 1254): AOT: image 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.App1-2/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
            11-04 23:11:01.698 D/Mono    ( 1254): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.App1-2/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
            11-04 23:11:01.698 D/Mono    ( 1254): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
            11-04 23:11:01.698 D/Mono    ( 1254): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
            11-04 23:11:01.746 D/Mono    ( 1254): Assembly mscorlib[0xb80f96d0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
            Could not connect to the debugger.
```

[image: Screenshot for crash]

Android output log: https://github.com/napzter13/masterdetail/blob/master/Android_OUTPUT.txt

I hope someone can help push me forward in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the logs when it crashes?

Comment: Sure, I added it to the post.

Comment: @smashingTheKeyboardTill - the error will likely be shown in your Output window, as to why it crashed.

Comment: @AdamPedley The output logs are in the POST ^

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is happening in your App.xaml.cs, and there could be some issue there. But here is how you would normally create an MDP. You do this in codebehind in the App.xaml.cs, it's a little easier than XAML. But you do all your other pages in XAML.

```
        var navPage = new NavigationPage(new PageOne()) { Title = "Title" };
        var mdp = new MasterDetailPage()
        {
            Master = new MasterPage(),
            Detail = navPage
        };

        MainPage = mdp;
```

You can put some sample XAML in each page to make sure it's visible.

Comment: Still the same problem, no matter what I do in the App.xaml.cs
Tried changing it to your example, but still the same...

Comment: Even If I download the MasterDetailPage sample from https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/ and open and run it, it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have solved the issue by doing the following:

- Droid project Properties > Both Release AND Debug > Android Options > Uncheck "Use Shared Runtime" and "Use Fast Deployment".
- Droid project Properties > Both Release AND Debug > Android Options > Advanced > Supported architectures > Check ALL.
- For building, use: Build > Deploy App1.Android . instead of: Build > Deploy Solution.

Yes, the reason it wouldn't work were that I compiled to the wrong architecture, therefor it only worked on one of the emulator versions. The Fast Deployment messed some things up too, so keep that off.

And if for some reason there still won't appear any .Apk file, right click on Android project and click "Archive..." and make a distributed copy by signing. (Hence the unchecking of 'Use Shared Runtime')